# How to connect nextjs with App insights using instrumentation hook and raise logs

Tags: next.js

I want to connect nextjs with the app insights. After reading about instrumentation hook. Implemented the below

`next.config.ts`
Added the below configuration

```
experimental: {
    instrumentationHook: true,
  },
```

`insturmentation.ts`

```
export async function register() {
  if (process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME === 'nodejs') {
    const appInsights = await import('applicationinsights');
    appInsights
      .setup(
        'connection string'
      )
      .setAutoCollectConsole(true)
      .setAutoCollectDependencies(true)
      .setAutoCollectExceptions(true)
      .setAutoCollectHeartbeat(true)
      .setAutoCollectPerformance(true, true)
      .setAutoCollectRequests(true)
      .setAutoDependencyCorrelation(true)
      .setDistributedTracingMode(appInsights.DistributedTracingModes.AI_AND_W3C)
      .setSendLiveMetrics(true)
      .setUseDiskRetryCaching(true);
    appInsights.defaultClient.setAutoPopulateAzureProperties();
    appInsights.start();
  }
}
```

So now the app insights setup is done. Now how to use this app insights in the pages. I can't able to import them into other tsx files.